# Cross-Browser Compatibility Testing

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Which tools do you use to test cross browser compatibility?

I have been using mostly chrome developer tools, but it is just not accurate.

I have tried to run some projects that I worked on through a couple of websites that say they can simulate different devices - but it is just not right (I am checking on a couple of different devices that I have access to).

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/browser-compatibility-testing-tools/

Comment: BrowserStack is always great for me

Comment: Thank you guys, great recommendations!

Answer (score -1):

Cross browser Testing, resembles to test or check the URL with different browsers.
The purpose is to identify that URL should behave or act in all the browsers similarly.